# yaml jackson Parsing using YAML Factory

Tags: jackson, yaml

We are trying to convert a YAML file into Objects and use them. When trying to parse the String with special characters, YAML Factory splits the String.

If you notice the output you see that the string is getting split.
Can you please help us with it? We tried to use the YAML features, but still could not succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :

Used the following feature of YAML GEnerator : SplitLINES

```
  YAMLFactory yf = new YAMLFactory();
  yf.disable(YAMLGenerator.Feature.SPLIT_LINES);
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(yf);
```

This is available in 2.6 feature od Jackon-yaml-databinding